# Returning the last return values of an iterator without storing a vararg in a table

Tags: performance, for-loop, lua, iterator, variadic-functions

Writing a function that takes a generic for loop iterator consisting of the iterator function, the invariant state & the loop control variable to return the value the control variable has in the last iteration is straightforward:

```lua
function iterator_last_value(iterator, state, control_var)
    local last
    for value in iterator, state, control_var do
        last = value
    end
    return last
end

print(iterator_last_value(("hello world"):gmatch"%a+")) -- world
```

This could be easily extended to support arbitrary constant numbers of arguments up to Lua's local register limit. We can also add vararg iterator return value support by always storing the last vararg in a table; this requires us to get rid of Lua's `for` loop syntactic sugar:

```lua
function iterator_last(iterator, state, control_var)
    local last = {}
    local last_n = 0
    local function iter(...)
        local control_var = ...
        if control_var == nil then
            return table.unpack(last, 1, last_n)
        end
        last = {...}
        last_n = select("#", ...)
        return iter(iterator(state, control_var))
    end
    return iter(iterator(state, control_var))
end

print(iterator_last(ipairs{"a", "b", "c"})) -- 3, c
```

which works well but creates a garbage table every iteration. If we replace

```lua
last = {...}
last_n = select("#", ...)
```

with

```lua
last_n = select("#", ...)
for i = 1, last_n do
    last[i] = select(i, ...)
end
```

we can get away with reusing one table - presumably at the cost of manually filling the table using `select` being less efficient than `{...}`, but creating significantly fewer garbage tables (only one garbage table per call to `iterator_last`).

**Is it possible to implement a variadic return value `iterator_last` *without* storing a vararg with significant overhead using a table, coroutine or the like, leaving it on the stack and only passing the varargs around through function calls?** I conjure that this is not possible, but have been unable to prove or disprove it.

Comment: I don't understand the "arbitrary number of arguments" thing. A generic for loop iterator is **always** three arguments... (if you only pass one or two, the extra ones are nil)

Comment: @user253751 the iterator can have an arbitrary number of return values, which is what I'm interested in. Let me revisit my phrasing.